# nosetests framework: how to pass environment variables to my tests?

Tags: python, nosetests

I have a test suite that gets executed as a part of a larger build framework, written in Python. Some of the tests require parameters, which I want to pass using environment variables.

Apparently the nosetests runner has an `env` parameter, which does what I want, [according to the documentation.](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core.html#nose.core.run) It seems, however, that it does not work as thought it should?

Here's a minimal test script that exemplifies the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pip install nose

import os, nose, unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_env(self):
        self.assertEquals(os.environ.get('HELLO'), 'WORLD')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.run(env={'HELLO': 'WORLD'})
```

The assertion fails, because the `env` parameter does not get passed to the test. Does anyone know why?

NB: I worked around the problem by launching the console `nosetests` tool:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, nose, unittest, subprocess

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_env(self):
        self.assertEquals(os.environ.get('HELLO'), 'WORLD')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.Popen(['nosetests', sys.argv[0]],
                     env={'HELLO': 'WORLD'}).wait()
```

However, this feels like a kludge, and I'd still be interested in learning to use `nose.run()` properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't get `env` to behave itself either, but I have come up with a solution that I consider slighly less kludgy than opening a subprocess. You can modify the `os.environ` variable before you call `nose.run()`, and as long as the tests are running in the same process, the tests will all see the modified `os.environ`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, nose, unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_env(self):
        self.assertEquals(os.environ.get('HELLO'), 'WORLD')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["HELLO"] = "WORLD"
    nose.run()
```

Comment: You'd still have to restore the old `os.environ` if you're doing something else after the tests ran, but this is something that can be factored into a method, I guess. I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The way I solved this problem was by using the **python-dotenv** pip module. I found this to be cleaner and easier to manage than having to manually set and then unset each variable inside of the test launcher shell script.

First, run:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Now, create a file called `.env.test` in your project root, and list environment variables in it (one on each line). For example:

```
FOO=bar
BAZ=qux
```

In a file called `tests/configuration.py`, place these contents:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

def setup_testing_environment():
    load_dotenv(find_dotenv(".env.test", raise_error_if_not_found=True))
```

Now, whenever you have a test file, all you have to do is call the `configuration.setup_testing_environment()` method at the very top to load in your test environment variables!

Here's a working example - create an example test file called `./tests/test_env_vars.py`, with these contents:

```
import os
import unittest

from tests.configuration import setup_testing_environment

setup_testing_environment()


class TestEnvironmentVars(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo_env_var_exists(self):
        self.assertEquals(os.getenv("FOO"), "bar")

    def test_baz_env_var_exists(self):
        self.assertEquals(os.getenv("BAZ"), "qux")
```

Comment: I don't use nose. This worked for getting my `.env` into my test file.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same type of situation where an environmental variable is required during testing.

I worked around using a bash script to set the environmental variable first, run the test, and then `unset` the environmental variable.

In `run_tests.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export HELLO='WORLD'
nosetests -v
unset HELLO
```

Then in the `tests/test_env.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_env(self):
        self.assertEquals(os.environ.get('HELLO'), 'WORLD')
```

To run the test, do 
`$ bash run_tests.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the nose sources (core.py and config.py) and traced the handling of the env argument. I think the env argument is not meant as you thought. It is not for setting or adding to the testee's environment. It is only for nose-specific configuration options.
Yet, it would be nice to have the feature you (and me too) were looking for.